# Magento2 image file in ui component form

Tags: magento2, image

I have ui component layout for an image field

```
     <field name="image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Showcase Image</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Allowed file types: ico, png, gif, jpg, jpeg, apng, svg. Not all browsers support all these formats!</item>
                <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="number">2097152</item>
                <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png svg</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">newstart_showcase_backend/showcase_image/upload</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

I have an **save.php** to save image name to database and another controller **newstart_showcase_backend/showcase_image/upload** to actually save the uploaded image to **media** folder. All these functions are working fine so far in "**add new item**" edit page. The real problem I have is image does not show when I open the **existing** item that I created. All other files are showing as expected, but not the image field. Any suggestion are appreciated. I can post more code here on demand if you need to check it. Thanks in advance.

Following is my main table **A**, and reference table **B** which stores  store ID for each item in table **A** by referring the **id**

```
id  smallint(5) unsigned Auto Increment Entity ID
image   varchar(255)    Image Name
url varchar(255) [] Image Destination Url
caption varchar(255) NULL   Image Caption
start_date  date NULL    
end_date    date NULL    
order   smallint(6) [1] Image Ordering
status  tinyint(1) [1]  1 - Banner Enabled, 0 - Banner Disabled
created_at  timestamp [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]   Created time
updated_at  timestamp [0000-00-00 00:00:00] Update time
```

At "**add new item**" page, there is uploader
[image]

Edit Page doesn't show image, and **HOW CAN I MAKE IT SHOW HERE**
[image]

Comment: I'd figure out how it's loading showcase as a source and what's going on with that object.

Comment: Do you have a DataProvider like this?
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php

Comment: @LM_Fielding, yes, I have DataProvider. But It's more like this one https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/Page/DataProvider.php. Because I referred to the Cms_Page module the time I developed mine. I just check the above one you posted, seems image need particular handles, which is not present in Cms_Page DataProvider.php. Could you shed light on this?

Comment: At the edit time you are unable to show the image?

Comment: @LM_Fielding, Do you have  completed working module which i can take a look at?

Answer (score 2):

Your DataProvider class's getData() method should include the image name & the image URL as an array like shown below:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
            $itemData = $item->getData();
            $imageName = $itemData['image_name']; // Your database field 
            unset($itemData['image_path']);
            $itemData['image_path'] = array(
                array(
                    'name'  =>  $imageName,
                    'url'   =>  $imageUrl // Should return a URL to view the image. For example, http://domain.com/pub/media/../../imagename.jpeg
                )
            );
            $this->loadedData[$item->getItemId()] = $itemData;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have one file in location:-
namespace\modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column['file_to_show_image'];

In my case its name is Thumbnail.php.

grid_item_form.xml is responsible to show the image at edit time:-

```
 <column name="profile" class="Dedicated\Employee\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Thumbnail</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

My file name is Thumbnail.php and the code is :-
Image will be fetch form here.

```
<?php
namespace Dedicated\Employee\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Thumbnail extends Column
{
const ALT_FIELD = 'title';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @param ContextInterface $context
 * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
 * @param Image $imageHelper
 * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
 * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param array $components
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {

    //die('d');
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare Data Source
 *
 * @param array $dataSource
 * @return array
 */
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{

    if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
        //print_r($fieldName); die();
        foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            $url = '';
            if($item[$fieldName] != '') {
                $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ).'dedicated/employees/'.$item[$fieldName];
            }
            $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $url;
            $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) ?: '';
            $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                'employee/entity_id/edit',
                ['entity_id' => $item['entity_id']]
            );
            $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $url;
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}

/**
 * @param array $row
 *
 * @return null|string
 */
protected function getAlt($row)
{
    $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
    return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
}
```

}

If you are facing any problem then let me know.

We list the image in two cashes :-
1.In listing page.
2.Edit or Update Page

Where do you want to show the image or fetch the image ? or show me some
screenshot so I could solve it better.

Comment: thank you for your answer first. It  seems you are talking about showing image in grid column. But I meant form field. I'd like to try your solution, but it doesn't make up for me at first glance. Or maybe I can't get your point clearly.

Comment: This code is for edit action when you edit the grid image will be fetch from Thumbnail.php.Are you still unable to get the answer ?

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Since the grid (also called listing) is also able to update the row (by click on the row), I'm afraid there is misunderstanding between you and me. If  your solution can make the image show in a form, then I will think the concept of (grid) column and (form) field are totally been messed up and cause lots of trouble to me.

Comment: Hi @ManishGoswami please let me know how I can add the image upload field in the admin form using ui component?

Comment: Hi @ Rajan you got the solution please let me know ?

Comment: And you want to upload image while form edit and new creation.. right ?

Comment: @ManishGoswami i am following your steps here.I can save the image but it wont appear in my grid. when i try to open the image i saved it gives me 404 could you help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You not setData for image in your DataProvider that why image not show up
DataProvider defined in your ui-component/yourform.xml

Usually it located in \Namespace\Module\Model\Entity\DataProvider

```
/**
 * DataProvider for your form
 */
class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
/** @var array **/
protected $loadedData;

/**
 * Get data from provider and populate
 * @param void
 * @return array
 */
public function getData()
{

    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }


    if ($menuId) {
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();

        /** @var \Namespace\Module\Model\YourItem $item */
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $_data = $item->getData();
            $item->load($item->getId());

            if (isset($_data['image'])) {
                $image = [];
                $image[0]['name'] = $item->getImagePath();
                $image[0]['url'] = $this->imageModel->getMediaUrl().'item/image'.$item->getImagePath();
                $_data['image'] = $image;
            }
            $item->setData($_data);
            $this->loadedData[$item->getId()] = $_data;
        }

    }

    return $this->loadedData;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/266166/17154