# How can I extend a Ui component JavaScript in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, extend

I know there is already [a topic](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2) about this, as well as [a documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html#extend_js_component), but I just can't get it to work:

How can I extend Ui Components' JavaScript in Magento 2?

I'm trying to extend `Magento_Ui/js/form/form` (located in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/form.js`).

So I added `requirejs-config.js` In my modules' `view/base`-folder:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "Magento_Ui/js/form/form": "Vendor_Module/js/form/form"
        }
    }
};
```

And in my file `base/web/js/form/form.js`:

```
define([
  "Magento_Ui/js/form/form"
], function(FormComponent){
  "use strict";

  /**
   * Rewrite original UI Component:
   */
  return FormComponent.extend({});
});
```

But for some reason, `FormComponent` is not the UI Component I'm trying to extends, but `undefined`.

According to the documentation, this should work, but it doesn't. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Please, describe your task, because I think that you don't need to override core form component. Looks like your component require itself because there is map in require config

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich Well, it's related to my other question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154201/magento-2-how-can-i-upload-files-of-dynamically-added-file-input-fields-in-the

I have dynamically added upload fields and I want to have those submitted as well when I save my form.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a requirejs "mixin".

First create `Your_Module/view/base/requirejs-config.js` with this code:

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/form': {
                'Your_Module/form-hook': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now make the file `Your_Module/view/base/web/form-hook.js` :

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (Form) {
        return Form.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                console.log('Hello from the mixin!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This example extends the initialize method of the `form` component.

You can read more about "mixins" here: http://alanstorm.com/the-curious-case-of-magento-2-mixins/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it.

Try to find declaration of ui component in code and replace it. For example:

*Magento_Checkout: LayoutProcessor.php*

```
private function processPaymentConfiguration(array &$configuration, array $elements)

...
$output[$paymentCode . '-form'] = [
    'component' => 'Vendor_Module/js/view/billing-address',
```

P.S. Don't use this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "Magento_Ui/js/form/form": "Vendor_Module/js/form/form"
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be caused by the **map** in your `requirejs-config.js`. I follow this method below, [mentioned in the DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html#extend_js_component).

### 1 - Create your custom Ui Component file

It can be inside one of these folders below, depending on if you're creating a module or theme customization.

**Theme:** `<theme_dir>/web/js` or `<theme_dir>/<VendorName>_<ModuleName>/web/js`

**Module:** `<module_dir>/view/frontend/web/js`

### 2 - Extend the default Ui Component

In your Ui Component, you will have to extend and call the default component, as the code below.

```
define([
  'Magento_Ui/js/default/component/path/here'
], function(DefaultComponentExample){

  return DefaultComponentExample.extend({

    defaults: { ... }, // properties with default values
    ... // methods of your component
  });
});
```

Comment: Your component code doesn't work because when you replace "Magento_Ui/js/form/form" with "Vendor_Module/js/form/form" in your map, "Magento_Ui/js/form/form" will reference "Vendor_Module/js/form/form" in your JS component. It's a circular reference.